# Failed to read key my-key-alias from store "myproject/android/keystores/debug.keystore.properties": Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, android, react-native, keystore, android-keystore

I already create a keystore file using this script

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias
> my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

I try to generate on myproject/android

[image]

in my android/gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true

MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=****** (my password)
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=****** (my password)
```

I have a folder named keystores store all the key

my BUCK file

```
keystore(
    name = "debug",
    properties = "debug.keystore.properties",
    store = "debug.keystore",
    visibility = [
        "PUBLIC",
    ],
)
```

my  debug.keystore.properties file

[image]

could anyone help me with this.

Comment: Have you also made changes in android/app/build.gradle? you will find more information in this link
https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/signed-apk-android#adding-signing-config-to-your-apps-gradle-config

Comment: I solved the issue i try to search all the project file with specific "my-key-alias" I found out that the gradle file inside of it (forgot the file name) is not same with my alias so i try to reedit on it.